# Avoiding interaction between if statements

Tags: python, flicker, inventory-management

I have an algorithm in a game that simplified looks like this:

```
if click:
    if a and not b and not c:
        b = True
        c = True
        follow_mouse_pos()

    if b and c:
        b = False
        c = False
        stay_on_slot()
```

This is for an inventory system, and the first if statement picks up an item from the clicked slot, and the other one puts it on the clicked slot.
The problem I have is that I want to have the same mouse button for both actions, but if I do that, the item just flickers between the slot and the mouse position.

a, b and c are conditions I have set up to decide wether I pick up the item or I put it in a slot.

a is irrelevant here because it is just for visual stuff.
b is True if the mouse is holding an item
c is True if the clicked slot is empty

The problem is that meeting one of the statements requirements will lead to meeting the conditions of the other statement, and it will loop as fast as the main loop goes. This is a problem because then I have to time it every time I want to move something in the inventory, and that is not good.

I have tried if elif statements but since this is in a loop, the only difference is that on each loop only one of them will be checked, but one of them will always be met.

Is there any way I can avoid this problem?

The full project is on [github](https://github.com/Kolterdyx/VoidShips/)

The file that contains this part of the code is here:
VoidShips/scripts/GUI/gui.py at line 203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that instead of one event "click", you have one like "mouse button up" and another "mouse button down".
Like this you could maybe build something like a drag and drop if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

just use if...elif, so if the 'if' condition checks it will not continue checking 'elif'.

Comment: I have tried that, but it constantly checks for both of them anyways, the only difference is that instead of checking both on each tick, it checks one of them, but each tick the other one is executed, giving me the flicker effect

Comment: Isn't that what you want, to follow mouse on a click and stay_on_slot on the next click?
the part in your code is # Pick Up/ #Drop ?
have you tried to add a boolean and change its value  if the first condition checks,  so in the second condition you know if you entered the first condition